# Trouble finding to get data in ratchet websocket

Tags: websocket, ratchet

I use this code in on Message function to check the data

```
public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from,$msg) 
{
    print_r($from->WebSocket->request->getQuery());
}
```

but the output of this code comes  as

```
Guzzle\Http\QueryString Object
(
    [fieldSeparator:protected] => &
    [valueSeparator:protected] => =
    [urlEncode:protected] => RFC 3986
    [aggregator:protected] =>
    [data:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

why data comes empty here?